# How to use Tensorflow's LSTM cell as part of a larger graph?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

The built-in LSTM cells give you a callable. However, I'd like to add static layers before and after the LSTM layers and train everything through backprop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

The cell `callable` is a function that takes an input `tf.Tensor` and the current state as a `tf.Tensor`, and returns an output `tf.Tensor` and the new state as a `tf.Tensor`. There is nothing special about the input/output and state tensors: these can be computed from and/or used as the inputs to other TensorFlow operations.

For an example, look at the [`ptb_word_lm.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dde1657e95f64be2c045aba140178b5220043de/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L120) model:

```
for time_step in range(num_steps):
  # ...
  (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
  outputs.append(cell_output)
```

Here, `inputs` is a 3-D tensor from which a slice is taken to get the input for one cell of the LSTM, and `state` is [initially](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dde1657e95f64be2c045aba140178b5220043de/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L98) computed using `cell.zero_state()`, then each subsequent iteration uses the state from the previous iteration.

The `inputs` tensor is the [result](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dde1657e95f64be2c045aba140178b5220043de/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L102) of a [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup) operation; the `outputs` list is [later concatenated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dde1657e95f64be2c045aba140178b5220043de/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L125) and used as the input to a loss calculation. TensorFlow backprops from the loss through the RNN and the embedding lookup back to the model variables.

Comment: I think that the method that you describe has the disadvantage that if the num_steps is very large the graph is going to take a lot of time and memory to be  initialized. Also if you don't know from the beginning the length of the time series (i.e streaming data) your network is going to process it would be useless.  Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, in some of those cases you should use [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn), which doesn't unroll the loop. There isn't currently a library method for handling streaming data, but the original question didn't have this requirement. For streaming data you could implement something using a `tf.while_loop()` but the current implementation is more efficient when you know the maximum number of timesteps ahead of time.